# Understanding Encoding Type

Tags: language-agnostic, encoding

i have an application which converts each character in my string to 3digit number, it seems to be something like ASCII but its not that, im trying to figure it out but i cant understand:

```
somefunction(){
   a => 934 // a will be converted to 934
   b => 933 // b will be converted to 933
   1 => 950 // 1 will be converted to 950
   0 => 951 // 0 will be converted to 951
}
```

i know ASCII but i don't understand this, please help if know what type of encoding type this is.

Thanks You :)

Comment: It could be custom encoding, why do you think it is some standard scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility (ord returns the ASCII value of the character), but I think you'd really need several more data points to know for certain.

```
>>> for c in 'ab10': print c, 999 - ord(c.upper())
...
a 934
b 933
1 950
0 951
```